# How to get the "Last Saved By" property for workbook file

Tags: vba, excel, file, winapi

In Windows Explorer, if I right-click a file and choose Properties to get the file's Properties window, and then select the Details tab, there is a property listed there called "Last Saved By". It seems to be the Windows account name that was logged in when the file was last modified.

I've looked in FileSystemObject but I don't see that the File object has such a property.

How do I get that property in VBA? Is there a Windows API for it?

UPDATE:

There are 3 attempts in this thread to do it with Shell's GetDetailsOf. I appreciate the effort but it seems pretty clear to me after trying them all (especially the code sample by OssieMac) that the text stored in the file system's "Last Saved By" field is not to be found in GetDetailsOf.

Scratching my head. How does Windows Explorer do it??

Comment: Try searching for GetDetailsOf for extended file properties

Comment: @mrbungle, thanks, I found this amazing code using GetDetailsOf (see OssieMac's reply:   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cead1384-b859-4466-9ef6-3d15cf76072b/change-in-respone-for-foldergetdetailsof-between-excel-2010-and-2013?forum=isvvba            ..........BTW not mentioned there is that you have to set a reference to "Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation"; it doesn't work to browse to shell32, and late binding with CreateObject didn't work for me. HOWEVER, it doesn't include Last Saved By. There is an "Authors" field but not same as "Last Saved By" in file system.

Comment: @GregLovern: which XL version do you need?

Answer (score 6):

Try this - the code uses the [BuiltinDocumentProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197172.aspx) class:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    MsgBox LastAuthor
End Sub

Function LastAuthor() As String
    LastAuthor = ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Author")
End Function
```

### EDIT

Using extended file properties - [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ee176615.aspx) reports that the magic number for `Author` is `9`. However, this number changes over time with Windows releases and since Vista has been `20` - see [this link](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/157286-view-extended-file-information-in-win7-like-winxp/). Further to some testing, you might also try `10` for Windows 10.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim varPath As Variant
    Dim varFileName As Variant

    varPath = "C:\Users\foo\bar\" '<~~ ensure final \
    varFileName = "lol.xlsx"


    'depending on OS version, try 9, 10 and 20
    Debug.Print GetAuthorFromShell(varPath, varFileName, 9)
    Debug.Print GetAuthorFromShell(varPath, varFileName, 10)
    Debug.Print GetAuthorFromShell(varPath, varFileName, 20)

End Sub

Function GetAuthorFromShell(varPath As Variant, varFileName As Variant, intProperty As Integer) As String

    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim strAuthor As String

    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(varPath) 

    With objFolder
        strAuthor = .getdetailsof(.Items.Item(varFileName), intProperty)
    End With

    GetAuthorFromShell = strAuthor

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great. But it requires opening the workbook, which takes a long time for a workbook that is very large and not local. Surely Windows Explorer isn't automating Excel to open the workbook to be able to display that property? Since Windows Explorer displays that property, it seems like there must be a Windows API or something for it, which would probably be much faster than opening a large workbook across a network.

Comment: thanks, but that code returns the string "Document" for me. In a comment above I have a link to some code that returns all (or very many anyway) of Shell's GetDetailsOf properties. One of them is Authors, But it does not return the same thing as the file system's Last Saved By.

Comment: Hm - think the magic number has been 20 since Vista - check my edit. HTH

Comment: Thanks again, but it returns "Microsoft Office User" for a file for which Windows Explorer's Properties Window > "Last Saved By" property is the full first and last name of the person who last modified it.

Comment: Can you try `10` - which is `Owner` - and see if that gets you the value you are looking for. I tested that edited code on WIndows 7 but agree, as it is not working on Windows 10 - but `10` is giving back my name. It seems this is very OS version dependent. Can you also mention what OS you are using?

Comment: Robin, the 2nd item there shows Owner, but the owner is a different person for the file I'm testing with than the person who last saved it. I'm on Windows 7, 64-bit (32-bit Excel). One of my comments above links to a code sample that returns GetDetailsOf items 1 - 286. None of those items are the person who last saved the file. But that person's full name (first & last) appears in the Windows Explorer file properties.

Answer (score 3):

This data is called `Extended File Properties` and stored in the NTFS metadata. You can read them using this script:

```
Dim arrHeaders(266)
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace("C:\Test.xtx")
For i = 0 to 265
 arrHeaders(i) = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolder.Items, i)
Next
For Each strFileName in objFolder.Items
 For i = 0 to 265
 Wscript.Echo i & vbtab & arrHeaders(i) _
 & ": " & objFolder.GetDetailsOf(strFileName, i)
 Next
Next
```

Note, that different OS versions has different amount of extended file properties. Windows 2000 allowed 35, Windows Vista extended property count to the 266.

**References:**

1) [Borrowing from Windows Explorer in PowerShell part 2: extended properties](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/jamesone/2008/12/09/borrowing-from-windows-explorer-in-powershell-part-2-extended-properties/)

2) [Retrieving Extended File Properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176615.aspx)

Comment: Ari0nhh, thanks, but when I run that (I'm on Windows 7), all elements in arrHeaders are empty strings (except the last one, which is Empty), and objFolder.Items has a count of 0. The only change I made to the code was swapping in the full path to my file in the Namespace line. objFolder.Self.Path does return the correct full path to the file (including filename).

Answer (score 0):

I, too was quite disappointed to find this to be true. Pity no response came.